# Create dynamic text files with data from another CSV file using python

Tags: python, csv

I need to dynamically create .txt files with the some portion of data from another CSV file. The csv file contains-

> "Cox's Bazar is the longest natural sea beach in the world. The beach
>   in Cox's Bazar is an unbroken 125 km sandy sea beach with a gentle
>   slope.It is located 150 km south of the industrial port Chittagong.
>
> The Sundarbans is a natural region comprising southern Bangladesh and a small part in the Indian state of West Bengal. It is the largest single block of tidal halophytic mangrove forest in the world"

What I need is to create two text files from this csv. As there is a new line between these two paragraphs I need to divide the csv file according to the paragraphs. If there are 3 paragraphs, there will be 3 different .txt files. Although I am new in python, my code is given below-

```
import csv
with open('INPUT_FILE.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
     for row in reader:
         print(row['text'])
```

I know how to detect a new line `if not row.strip():` is to be used. But I can't just make the conditions right between these two codes. Or is there a better solution for this? Any kind of help would be much appreciated. I am kind of stuck here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: that's not a csv file.

Comment: @muratgu actually I converted the file from json to csv that's why I have to extract text content using csv reader using the 'text' label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input is not in CSV (*comma separated values*) format, it is plain text. So you don't need to worry about the `csv` module.

Open the input file, read a line and, if it is not an blank line, open an outfile and write the line to it.

You already know how to detect blank lines using `strip()`, so you could write it like this:

```
file_count = 1
with open('INPUT_FILE.csv') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip():
            with open('output_file_{}.txt'.format(file_count), 'w') as outfile:
                outfile.write(line)
                file_count += 1
```

This assumes that each paragraph consists of one line.

Another way to do it is with `itertools.groupby()`. This makes it easy to handle multiple lines per paragraph:

```
from itertools import groupby

file_count = 1
with open('INPUT_FILE') as infile:
    for k, lines in groupby(infile, key=lambda line: line.strip() != ''):
        if k:
            with open('output_file_{}.txt'.format(file_count), 'w') as outfile:
                outfile.writelines(lines)
            file_count += 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :D the second one worked like a charm!
What I did is- extracted the text content I needed from the csv file and saved it into a .txt file altogether. Then used `itertools.groupby()` to save them into individual text files like you mentioned above.